# What do these special characters mean in Java?

Tags: regex, java

I was looking at some of the jdk code. I found these characters. Could someone explain to me what do these mean.

```
public static String quote(String s) {
    int slashEIndex = s.indexOf("\\E");        // What does this mean. Is this a special char in java. if so what does this do.
    if (slashEIndex == -1)
        return "\\Q" + s + "\\E";          

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() * 2);
    sb.append("\\Q");
    slashEIndex = 0;
    int current = 0;
    while ((slashEIndex = s.indexOf("\\E", current)) != -1) {
        sb.append(s.substring(current, slashEIndex));
        current = slashEIndex + 2;
        sb.append("\\E\\\\E\\Q");
    }
    sb.append(s.substring(current, s.length()));
    sb.append("\\E");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

From the above code example I was able to figure out what's happening as in the method finds the occurrences of \ and converts them to \E and \Q. Could someone explain why that's the case.

For more context on this method, I was looking into the Pattern.quote() method from jdk 1.6

Comment: This code appears to be [lifted straight from Java sources](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.java.html) (`Pattern.java`, lines 1276..1293).

Comment: Yes it is from the jdk sources Pattern.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\Q` and `\E` is exactly what `Pattern.quote()` does, that is to **Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String.**

**For more details see this link:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 11):

Java regex engine blocks special interpretation of all meta-characters between `\Q` and `\E`. For example, `[name]` matches a single character (`'n'`, `'a'`, `'m'`, or `'e'`), while `\Q[name]\E` matches six characters - `'['`, `'n'`, `'a'`, `'m'`, `'e'`, and `']'`. See the *Special Characters* section of the [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) for more detail.

The method makes a regular expression from a string that is presumably provided externally (e.g. entered by a user). Since the string may contain meta-characters, the method encloses the entire string in `\Q` and `\E`. If the string already contains a `\E`, the method inserts the end of the quote, a match of `\E`, and a beginning of a new quote for each `\E` that it finds..

Answer (score 3):

Well, `\Q` and `\E` have a special meaning in Java [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quot)...

Most of this method is just working on the tricky edge case of quoting the quote markers `\Q` and `\E` themselves.